# Combobox not taking the first update event

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm setting up a simple form using reactJs + semantic-ui-react.
It works fine but, strangely enough, the first update event on the select is not taken:

> I change value on the dropdown--> nothing happens, it retains the previous one-->I do that again--> it works

I think it has something to do with the initial state: If I don't put any it seems to be working but I don't like an empty combobox. This is my code snippet:

```
class MyForm extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selected: 'A'
    };
}

handleComboChange = evt => {
    console.log('combo change');
    this.setState({ selected: evt.target.value });
}

render() {

    const myOpts = [
        { text: 'A state', value: 'A' },
        { text: 'B state', value: 'B' },
    ];

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group widths="equal">
                <Form.Select onChange={this.handleComboChange} fluid label="State" options={myOpts} value={this.state.selected} />
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>);
```

}
    }

**edit**:
Interesting enough seems to be a problem related to semantic-ui, the following works fine:

```
<select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleComboChange}>
                    <option value='A'>A state</option>
                    <option value='B'>B state</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved...semantic-react has its own way to define events, I had to change my handling function like this:

```
handleComboChange = (evt,data) => {
console.log('combo change');
this.setState({ selected: data.value });
```

}